Problem with lables on the boundary between two tiles with Tiled mode
I tried to play with SLD styles to find a reason for lables cutting on the boundary between two tiles on different scales. We found this bug on point labes layers, which don't have polygonal area around them. To understand is there the same problem on Geoserver standard label layers, we used layer named ne:populated_places and appropriate style populated_places.
So on the scale Scale = 1 : 70M or Scale = 1 : 35M we can see that lables don't fit in tile area. So is it possible to solve sthis probplem useing SLD or is it more deep problem linked with the system Geeoserver WMS logic?
labels screenshot - 1
labels screenshot - 2

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/156904/79 for an answet
